# Generated identity JWT token in .net 6 WebApi passed back to Blazor Server Side, how to use with Identity?

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have 2 .Net 6 projects.
WebApi which does all the business logic and database calls etc.
Blazor Server Side site that acts as a WebUI.

Part of the logic the webapi will handle is the login of a user. User accounts are now setup for MS Identity.

What I wish to do is have a login page in blazor which sends the username and password to the api. The Api validates and then sends back a JWT token with user claims etc, if all is good.
I am then assuming that blazor can then use this JWT token to validate the user has logged in and can allow access to the rest of the site. I can then setup views per policy etc.

So I have the following working.

WebApi login logic and the return of the JWT token with claims etc.
I have a blazor login (razor page) which sends the request to the api.
I have setup a custom AuthenticationStateProvider which saves/loads the token to local storage.

This is my GetAuthenticationStateAsync code.

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity;

        var securityTokenString = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityTokenString))
        {
            api.SetDefaultHeader(securityTokenString);
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        }
        else
        {
            var securityToken = GetTokenFromResult(securityTokenString);

            if (securityToken is not null)
            {
                api.SetDefaultHeader(securityTokenString);
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(securityToken.Claims, "JWT");
            }
            else
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            }
        }            

        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)));
    }
```

My login page simply has this in the submit button.

```
await authStateProvider.Login(loginRequest); //loginRequest contains username and password

navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
```

and finally my App.razor page is this.

Determining session state, please wait...

Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

So my issue is I have something missing on the blazor server side project, in regards to handling the returned JWT token.

If I run the above code and put a breakpoint here `navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");` I can safely say that I have a valid returned JWT token, I can create a new `ClaimsIdentity` from the token and I can validate `IsAuthenticated` is true, yet when I continue execution the login page loads again as if to say I am not authorised.

I have checked Program.cs for the correct order of the following.

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

So I am assuming I need to do something more with the JWT token to get everything in the blazor server side working right. I know that blazor server side is using SignalR so login pages have to be in .cshtml, but is this still the same when login logic is an external source?

Everything I have read online seems to show how to use identity in one project or for a webapi and the client is a webui in Angular or similar.

UPDATE:
Think I got this working. Just as I thought, like an all-in-one Blazor Server Side app, you need to use a Login.cshtml page and not a typical blazor component page.
In the `POST`, once the returned JWT token is authenticated and a `ClaimsIdentity` has been created from it, you can use it to run the following.

```
//User = my ClaimsIdentity from JWT token
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, User );
return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Why use JWT tokens at all and not just simple session cookie authentication?

Comment: because I am using a WebApi which uses JWT tokens for Authentication/Authorization.

Comment: Its a challenge to generate your own JWT tokens that an API will trust, both the client and the API needs to have the same signing key.

Comment: @ToreNestenius they do have the same signing key? Found that part pretty easy to do.

Comment: Good, its just a common thing that many forgets about :-)

Comment: Indeed. Use cookie authentication + antiforgery middleware